# AngularJs 1.5 - Pass data to nested components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to compose components in `AngularJs 1.5` in a way they propagate data to the nested components (I am new to Angular). My first intention was to use service injection (which would restrict the component to only have a single service type per application). So we came up with the idea to nest the components. Let me show you the intention ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWsaGIEkXDlBG3Orfsxg?p=preview))

```
<fetcher>
  <consumer items="$ctrl.items">
</fetcher>
```

As far as I understand, we need to use transclusion and a corresponding binding of the items to achieve that:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .component('fetcher', {
    template: `<nav ng-transclude></nav>` ,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function(){
      this.items = [
        {name: 'One'},
        {name: 'Two'}
      ];
    }
  })
  .component('consumer', {
      template: `{{$ctrl.items | json}}`
    , bindings: { items: '<' }
  });
```

Sadly the values do not seem to be available within the controller of the `consumer`. I already tried to use `$scope`s but it doesn't seem to work out.

Please note, it is an important requirement that we do not need to couple concrete components (i.e. using the require property).

Am I following a completely wrong approach?
Thx in advance.

Comment: you code will work if you place consumer element in template member directly. Is there any reason you need transclude for fetcher component? Look at my post http://www.siddharthpandey.net/use-angularjs-components-with-typescript/

Comment: @SiddharthPandey Yes, because I don't want to couple the fetcher and the consumer explicitly and be able to replace the consumer by simply editing the corresponding view template.